# java.lang.NullPointerException when adding two numbers

Tags: java, command-line

I'm new to java and am trying to write a simple program that basicly asks for user input and then returns the average. I keep getting `java.lang.NullPointerException` when trying to add. Why is this? This is the code I have so far.

```
import java.io.*;
class Numbers {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
            System.out.println("Hello USER! This is TRON, state the number of NUMBERS you wish to enter and I will return the Average..."); // Display the string.
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            Integer loopnum = null;
            Integer i = null;
            Long num = null;
            Long sum = null;
            Long avg = null;

            try {
                loopnum = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());

            }
            catch(IOException e){
                System.out.println("Error!");
                System.exit(1);
            }
            System.out.println("OK now enter your numbers.");
            for (i=1;i<=loopnum; i++) {
                try {
                System.out.println("Enter number "+i+":");
                num = Long.parseLong(br.readLine());
                sum += num;
                }
                catch(IOException e){
                    System.out.println("Error!");
                    System.exit(1);
                }
            }

                avg = sum / loopnum;
                System.out.println("TRON here, Your average is: " + avg);




    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initialize! Change declaration to `Long sum = 0L` at the beginning of your code. This line is problematic in your loop:

```
sum += num;
```

it's same as `sum = sum + num;` Evaluation is done from the right to left and you see it tries to add variable `num` with a `null` variable sum.

Comment: using a primitive long would be even better. Also, evaluation from right to left would also result in an NPE.

Comment: Because it's not trying to add sum to null, rather it's calling longValue on a null reference.

Answer (score 1):

You should initialize your `Long` variables in `0L`, not `null`. Even better, use the primitive type `long` instead of the wrapper type `Long` and `int` instead of `Integer`, you don't need to use wrapper objects here! Do this:

```
int loopnum = 0;
int i = 0;
long num = 0L;
long sum = 0L;
long avg = 0L;
```

The above will get rid of the `NullPointerException` and will avoid the unnecessary boxing/unboxing of values between primitive and object data types.

Answer (score 1):

All the other answers fail to address why you're getting the null pointer exception. You are using the `Long` object instead of the `long` primitive. Thus anytime you use a direct arithmetic operation (such as `+`), the compiler will unbox `Long` into `long` by invoking [`Long.longValue()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#longValue%28%29). So `sum += sum` gets translated to:

```
sum = Long.valueOf(sum.longValue() + sum.longValue());
```

Since `sum` is null you'll end up with a null pointer exception. Most people avoid this by just using the primitve `long`.

Answer (score -3):

initialize your sum variable with a non null value. 0L perhaps.

replace this line `sum += num` with `sum = sum + num`.. this is more readable.